# Selenium + Python: WebDriverWait TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am new to Selenium and Python.
I am able to navigate through a website, find an element and print it but it is running slow & sometimes fails when the server takes too long to respond because I am using time.sleep(3) throughout my code instead of Explicit Wait.
I have never been able to get the Explicit Wait to work.

Python version: 3.10; Selenium Webdriver: Firefox; IDE: PyCharm 2021.3.2 (CE);
OS: Fedora 35 VM

HTML code of an element I am trying to print:

```
<input id="b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"
class="form-control OSFillParent" data-
input="" disabled="" type="text"
style="margin-top: 5px;" value="$10.50">
event
```

My Python Selenium Locate code that works most of the time (but fails when the server takes too long to respond):

```
print('Remaining 2022 Deductible:',driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.OSFillParent[id$='Input_RemainAmtYr1']").get_attribute("value"))
```

My Explicit Wait code that produces errors:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.OSFillParent[id$='Input_RemainAmtYr1']"))).get_attribute("value"))
```

This is the Traceback that is produced from my Explicit Wait code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/usr/Documents/Training/Python_Automation_Testing/Exercise Files/print_value.py", line 122, in 
> print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.OSFillParent[id$='Input_RemainAmtYr1']"))).get_attribute("value"))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Note : I am using the following imports :

> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Comment: Have you set `driver.implicitly_wait()`?  If so, what are you setting?

Comment: Also, you mention you using implicit waits but also mention using `time.sleep`; these are not the same thing.  Implicit waits are when you tell the _driver_ "always wait x seconds to find elements".  Whereas using `time.sleep` is telling the _script_ to wait.

Comment: I thought time.sleep was an implicit wait. Thanks for the clarification. I have only been using time.sleep. I would like to use Explicit Waits to prevent my code from failing when the server is slow to respond and to allow my code to run faster when the page has loaded quickly.

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change out `visibility_of_element_located` for `presence_of_element_located`?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I can not post the URL. I can post more HTML if that is of any use.

Comment: @MarcelWilson No. WebDriverWait does work in my code if I use 'presence_of_element_located'. It does locate the element & I am able to extract the text attribute of that element. But I am concerned because apparently best use dictates that I should use 'visibility_of_element_located' if I want to extract any attribute of any element & I do need to extract the text attribute. Have you used 'presence_of_element_located'  when you need to extract the text attribute of an element? Have you run into any issues with that?

Comment: @Auditor `presence_of_element_located` finds the element but doesn't care if it's visible whereas `visibility_of_element_located` does.  Since the element can be found using presence, it suggests that something is occurring which does not allow the element to be considered "visible".  What browser are you using?

Comment: I also need to ask: is there more to that stacktrace error?  Is the exception message actually blank?

Comment: @Auditor to answer your question 'have I used presence', yes but only in situations where it made sense to do so.  Like if I'm looking for an element that _should_ be invisible.  I didn't suggest you change your test to use presence, I only asked because it gives you something to troubleshoot as you begin to figure out why visibility wasn't working.  It's usually a clue for me to look at the timing of things.  Or is it possible there is a layer on top of the element in question that is preventing it from being considered 'visible'?

Comment: @MarcelWilson I am starting to understand now. The element I am trying to extract the text attribute from is not visible on the page unless another tab is clicked. I didn't bother adding the Selenium code to click that tab first because the locate code was able to extract the text attribute prior to adding WebDriverWait to it. When I did add WebDriverWait, I was using 'visibility_of_element_located' even though that element was not visible. Thank you for the explanation. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @MarcelWilson Do you think it is okay to leave the code as 'presence_of_element_located' even though I am extracting text from it or should I change the code to click the tab first and then use 'visibility_of_element_located'?

Comment: I would normally advise doing whatever actions need to be taken to make the element visible first.

Answer (score 1):

### Changing Tabs

From your comments, it sounds as if you are **opening a new tab** and the element you are looking for is on the page of that tab.

In which case **you need the driver to switch to that tab** before looking for the element:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

*Change the **index of window_handles to the tab you want to focus on**

Also note that after you have finished on that tab (i.e you have closed it and gone back to the original tab), **you will need to tell the driver to switch back again** using the same line of code.

### TimeoutException returned as boolean

Anyone visiting this page because they **want the TimeoutException to return a boolean value** instead of throwing an exception, you can try something like this:

```
#return boolean value instead of throwing exception
def check_elem_exists(parent, by, selector, wait=False, timeout=False):
    if not wait:
        try:
            parent.find_element(by, selector)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    #when allowing wait time - print note for what is happening
    print('%s - check_elem_exists(%is..)' %(selector,timeout))
    try:
        WebDriverWait(parent, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, selector)))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    except TimeoutException:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#search without wait time
elem1 = check_elem_exists(driver, By.XPATH, "//div[@class='elem1']")
#search with wait time (i.e waiting for page to load)
elem2 = check_elem_exists(driver, By.XPATH, "//div[@class='elem2']", True, 10)
```

Find useful XPATH cheatsheet: 
https://devhints.io/xpath